# Dual Boot Problems Windows 8 & Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop with Windows 8 pre- installed. But when selecting Windows 8 to boot i get following error. error: unknown command ´drivemap'error: invalid EFI filepath

I ran boot repair. the output can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6995882/

I hope anyone can help me!

Thank you!

Comment: Which Windows boot entry are you using? You should be booting sda3 or UUID 1CD4-9FB5 entries. If Boot-Repair offers to run 'buggy' UEFI do not say yes until confirmed that you do have a buggy UEFI. Can you boot Windows from UEFI menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you report indicates that you're trying to boot with the "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2)" or "Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" entries. Those entries are both suitable for BIOS-mode Windows installations, but you've clearly got an EFI-mode installation. Thus, you should be using the "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi", "Windows Boot UEFI loader", "Windows UEFI recovery bootmgfw.efi", or "Windows Boot UEFI recovery" entries. (Probably the first of those.)

If none of those entries work, then something is wrong. In this case, I recommend you download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) prepare a medium with it, and boot to that medium. You should be able to boot to both Windows and Ubuntu with rEFInd. If this works, install the Debian-package version of rEFInd in Ubuntu. The computer should then boot to rEFInd when you reboot, and you can use rEFInd as your default boot manager. rEFInd tends to be much less finicky about booting Windows than is GRUB, so using it instead of GRUB as your primary boot manager often fixes problems like this.

Comment: Hi Rod&oldfred, I installed Refind under Ubuntu and it works the first time I used it. Now Windows 8 is loading after turning on the Computer. I had the same problem with Grub. Sometimes it appears and sometimes it doesnt. But now obviously its like Windows is staring every time and no Grub and no Refind. Refind showed me many different options like starting Windows and Ubuntu. I tried to install Ubuntu several times before and then tried to delete the partition after I had trouble with installing Grub 2 in the installationprocess. So there is maybe some crap on the harddrive I have to clean?

Comment: finally Windows and Ubuntu is on the PC but only Windows is starting and Refind and Grub arent working anymore.

Comment: I used EasyUS Partiton manager to manage the partitons on the harddrive but my knowledge is not to big to handle that.

Comment: EaseUS Partition Manager won't help; your problem is ***not*** related to partitioning; Windows is aggressively taking over the top spot in your firmware's boot manager. I recommend booting to Windows, opening an *Administrator* command prompt window, and typing `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi` in that window. This usually fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi Rod, thank you very much for your help! It worked, till now ;) ! Refind is now my boot manager! Is it possible that Windows is also booting when I am working with Ubuntu? there was this failure message as I want to open the windwos partition:

Comment: Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is hibernated. Please resume and shutdown Windows
properly, or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option, or
mount the volume read-write with the 'remove_hiberfile' mount option.
For example type on the command line:

            mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda5 /media/547EDF0E7EDEE82E

Comment: That latest error is probably caused by the Windows "Fast Startup" feature. You should disable it, as described [here,](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) among other places.